# Selenium webdriver error:Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

Error log:-

> Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106
>   (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882})
>   on port 37282 Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports
>   used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by
>   malicious code. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver
>   server to start. Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision:
>   'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48' System info: host:
>   'DESKTOP-76F21OU', ip: '192.168.93.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211' Driver info:
>   driver.version: ChromeDriver  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>     at random_try.javaproject.main(javaproject.java:9) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
>   for [http://localhost:37282/status] to be available after 20002 ms    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>     ... 10 more

code is simply hit the url:-

```
package random_try;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class javaproject {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\sele_server\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.tpplsqa.com");

    }
}
```

Tried everything even downgraded chrome version as well as chrome driver version to 79 but it's not working.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context like version of chrome and selenium are you using, etc. This will help others to answer your question more promptly.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all open chrome instances, it might solve your problem if it doesn't try upgrading your Java version. Maybe switching to another version of Chrome might also fix the problem because you need to use the right version of chrome and chromedriver, because for me it looks like you aren't using the right version of Chrome.

Are you sure your versions of chrome and Chromedriver are compatible?